# Why is Graphene So Strong?

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, atoms, graphene

*There has been a lot of news about Graphene since its discovery in 2004.* And as we are all told it is a revolutionary material which is very strong, conductive and transparent.

But what is it about the **structure of Graphene which makes it so strong**?

Answer (score 5):

In a perfect graphene sheet, all carbon atoms are sp$^2$-hybridized, with three in-plane $\sigma$-orbitals and two out-of-plan $\pi$-orbitals. This means that each carbon atom can form equivalent s-bonds to each of its three neighboring atoms. The bonding energy of one C-C bond in graphene amounts to 4.93 eV [doi:10.1088/0953-8984/14/4/312]. These strong (covalent) $\sigma$-bonds are responsible for the extraordinary mechanical properties of graphene.

The out-of-plane orbitals are responsible for the $\pi$ bands (Dirac cones) and lead to the nice electric properties of graphene, but they do not significantly contribute to the mechanical "strongness" of graphene.

Answer (score 2):

Graphene's strength mainly comes from the **strong covalent bonds** of the **carbon atoms**.

Graphite is made of layers of graphene but it is weaker because the layers making up graphite are bonded to each other through **London forces** hence why the layers can slide past each other and the material is soft. These weak inter-layer London forces provide a **weak point** in graphite's structure which doesn't exist in graphene.

Answer (score 1):

What makes Graphene so strong is its electrostatic forces resulting from delocalized electrons flowing through positively charged carbon atoms. This diffrence in charge creates a strong electrostatic attraction that holds Graphene together. This phenomenon also explains why it is such a strong conductor.